# SQLite can't read table create with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQL table from CSV file using Python sqlite3 library.
That's the code I wrote:

```py
import csv
import sqlite3


csv_file = 'path/to/file.csv'
db = sqlite3.connect('clients.db')
db.execute('''CREATE TABLE main(
                ID          INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
                name        VARCHAR,
                email       VARCHAR,
                address    VARCHAR);''')
# That part is only for getting the number of rows in the table
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_table: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_table, delimiter=';')
    rows = sum(1 for r in reader)
# Here I'm reading the table
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_table:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_table, delimiter=';')
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        db.execute('''INSERT INTO main VALUES 
        ('{idn}', '{name}', '{email}', '{add}');'''.format(idn=i,
                                      name=row['name'],
                                      email=row['email'],
                                      add=row['address']))
        print('{}/{}:\t{}'.format(i+1, rows, row))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

After I've run this code I tried to access the table with sqlite3 but I got the error message: "Error: no such table: main" anytime I've send a query regarding 'main' table.

I've tried to read the table with Python and it works fine:

```py
import sqlite3


db = sqlite3.connect('clients.db')
rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM main;')
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

I'm running this script from the same directory that I'm running SQLite3.

I'm using Python 3.6 and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Wild guess.  As you do not use full paths, Python works in one folder and sqlite3 in another one, so they use 2 different databases.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just change it to full paths and it's working, thanks.

Comment: Feel free to use my comment to build an answer and later accept it to avoid leaving an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Python and sqlite3 were actually running on different locations so they used different databases.

I've changed

```py
db = sqlite3.connect('clients.db')
```

to

```py
db = sqlite3.connect('full/path/to/clients.db')
```

and  now it's working fine.